# Turn X number of array entrees into individual variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am sorry if the title is misleading but I'm really not sure how to title this.

Anyways, I have an array - $code_array[0];

This calls onto a a column on a table with 2000+ entrees, so $code_array[2000] would work.

Depending on the situation, I may want to call on 10,20,30,40,even 50 codes. I need to do this without manually changing the script. The amount I need to call on will be in variable $quantity.

So how exactly can I call on $code_array[0-$quantity]?

Comment: How do you want to store these variables? In a string? Separated by what delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would comment but dont have the rep.

The count command should help you here

[Have a look at this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp)

It will make it pretty straight forward if you displaying the elements immediately.